# Apache - Htaccess Redirection Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how can i redirect my links

For Example
`http://example.com/my-goat-eats-grass/ -> http://example.com/example-text-my-goat-eats-grass/`

but keeping in mind that this redirection should not affect

`http://example.com/tags/abc/`
or
`http://example.com/categories/abc/`
or
`http://example.com/authors/abc/`

yaa i am using wordpress

and have thousand of pages like 
`http://example.com/my-goat-eats-grass/`

Please help me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create thousounds of lines:

```
RewriteRule ^my-goat-eats-grass$ http://www.example.com/example-text-my-goat-eats-grass/ [L,R=301]
```

Or try this, after discussion:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!example-text-)([^/]+)/?$ /example-text-$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Hmm... Someone can create you this lines by money

Comment: wt if i post new content and then new url will get generated.. who will add this new URL..?

Comment: There is no enough information to create a regex rule for you situation. I need to explain, "what" part of this URL is enough to separate it from URL's you don't want to redirect.

Comment: kidding me?

Please help me genuinely need help

Comment: yaa i can tell u the difference..

the links i wanna redirect have only one `"/"` that too at the end and the links which i dont want to redirect have more than one `"/"`

Comment: I updated my answer. I have no apache now (using nginx on all servers), but I think that this may help you.

Comment: It's because i forget last slash. Check now with `/?`

Comment: yaa it worked after last slash..

`RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/example-text-$1 [L,R=301]`

Genius you are

Comment: add question symbol. Because of whitout it you cannot redirect `http://example.com/blabla`, only `http://example.com/blabla/`

Comment: only problem is if i am calling `http://example.com/i-love-girls` it redirects to `http://example.com/example-text-i-love-girls` and gives 404 error becaiuse there is no such page but if page exists then it redirects twice like 
`http://example.com/i-love-girls > http://example.com/example-text-example-text-i-love-girls`

Comment: yes. Because of `/example-text-i-love-girls/` is the first level and satisfy the condition. Create a subfolder or subroot in your CMS to `/example-text/i-love-girls`

Comment: its not happening can't we do this without creating a physical folder

Comment: Check my answer. I create a new condition.

Comment: This is exactly the answer.. Thanks Brother.. you are awesome at u r logical thinking.. you are a star...